How to generate an index for the Songs package in TexStudio?
I am trying to make a song book for Christmas songs, and I can typeset the songs ok, but not figure out how to get the index showing correctly - it just says "index not yet generated" - I get that but how do I do this in my windows TexStudio setup?
I have the following in my document (which shows the placeholder indicated above):
\newindex{Julesange}{julesangeindexfil}
\makeindex

...
\showindex[2]{Indhold}{Julesange}

How do I generate the file in TexStudio and what else is needed, so I can show my index in the document?
Sample code (more songs in the real file):
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

%DK Setup
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Other setup
\usepackage{songs}


\title{Julesange}
\author{Jane Noesgaard Larsen}

\newindex{Julesange}{julesangeindexfil}
\makeindex


\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \showindex[2]{Indhold}{Julesange}

    
    \songsection{}
    
    
    
    \begin{songs}{}
        
        \beginsong{Glade Jul}[]

        \beginverse
        Glade jul, dejlige jul,
        engle daler ned i skjul!
        Hid de flyver med paradisgrønt,
        hvor de ser, hvad for Gud er kønt,
        lønlig iblandt os de går,
        - lønlig iblandt os de går!
        \endverse
        
        \beginverse
        Julefryd, evige fryd,
        hellig sang med himmelsk lyd!
        Det er englene, hyrderne så,
        dengang Herren i krybben lå,
        evig er englenes sang,
        - evig er englenes sang.
        \endverse
        
        \beginverse
        Fred på jord, fryd på jord,
        Jesusbarnet blandt os bor!
        Engle sjunger om barnet så smukt,
        han har Himmerigs dør oplukt,
        salig er englenes sang,
        - salig er englenes sang.
        \endverse
        
        \beginverse
        Salig fred, himmelsk fred
        toner julenat herned!
        Engle bringer til store og små
        bud om ham, som i krybben lå;
        fryd dig, hver sjæl, han har frelst,
        - fryd dig, hver sjæl, han har frelst!
        \endverse
        
        \endsong
                
    \end{songs}
\end{document}
    

This compiles and shows up as it should exept for the index - I am sure I miss some extra action in getting the index built but not sure what :)

Please show some short version, which compiles. Thank you

The index is generated by a separate program (Makeindex) between runs.  I'n not familiar with TexStudio, but with my program one would look under the Project->Properties menu.

I hav not yet found anything where I can run another program or build index in the TexStudio

Actually, in the newest version, it’s a texlua program. P.S. I have an official monopoly on using songs for creating Danish Christmas songbooks.  Glædelig jul!

Anyway, you’re supposed to run songidx.lua using texlua from the command line, as documented here.

If I run the command: texlua songidx.lua julesangeindexfil.sxd julesangeindexfil.sbx it says:
songidx: Unable to open julesangeindexfil.sxd for reading.
Error 2: julesangeindexfil.sxd: No such file or directory
How do I generate that file?
